# How to get URL of web-service method in android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have to write XML to my SD card for that I want to get input-Stream but to establish this how can I get URL when I call any method from android?

For instance I want to download all login details containing 10,000 records when I call it from android that method is called but how to get URL so that I can establish connection and get Input Stream to write to file...Please help me on this below is my code

```
public void DownloadFiles(){

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.10/INIFARM/fieldbook/webservice1.asmx?wsdl");
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        File testDirectory = new File("/data/data/com.example.androidwebservice/");
        if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
            testDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory + "/response.xml");
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        long total = 0;
        int progress = 0;
        while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;
            if (progress_temp % 10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp) {
                progress = progress_temp;
            }
            fos.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        is.close();
        fos.close();
        Log.v(TAG, "File is Downloaded Successfully");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the URL to call? Your web server admin needs to create a REST API for this and tell you the url so that your app can consume the data by querying this API.

Comment: I am having 4 different methods which I am calling onClick Download data button...have to download 10,000 thousand records so I want to write these on SD Card first and then use it..Please tell me how can I get these URL's so that I can make connection to get InputStream...Thanks in advance